# Ошибка при запуске mssql-server в fedora 25

Tags: linux, sql-server

Привет всем, пытаюсь запустить mssql-server на fedora 25, как в этом руководстве.
https://fedoramagazine.org/run-sql-server-v-next-public-preview-fedora/

```
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Вс 2016-12-18 13:01:49 +07; 10s ago
  Process: 2375 ExecStart=/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 2375 (code=exited, status=127)

дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) Database Engine.
дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Microsoft(R) SQL Server(R) Database Engine.
дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
дек 18 13:01:49 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mssql-server.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

Comment: Ну-у-у, как минимум посмотреть логи (Обычно в `/var/log`), запустить "с руки" `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr` и посмотреть, на что демон ругается в консоль, дальше действовать по ситуации.

Comment: в логе ничего более нет. /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr зап

Comment: в логе ничего более нет. /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr запускается удачно

Comment: Странно, оно говорит что не может чего-то найти (status 127). Посмотрите `systemctl status mssql-server.service` и чего пишут в `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service`

Answer (score 1):

Была ошибка в `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service`

Путь до *sqlserver* был прописан в `/opt/mssql/etc/default/sqlservr`